# AngularJS Event - dom is delayed updating

Tags: angularjs

In my app, I have an event that listens for new messages sent to a user. Upon receiving the event, it runs a factory function to retrieve messages. However, it seems as though it is always 1 event behind (ie, event 1 data doesn't display until event 2 occurs).

I have a feeling this has to do with the digest cycle. I have tried $scope.$apply, $timeout to no avail. Hopefully I have been clear enough.

```
$scope.retrieveMessages = function(){
    Conversations.retrieveConversations($scope.authentication.uid)
      .then(function(success){
          $scope.messageList = success;
      }, function(error){
          console.log(error);
    });    
};


$scope.$on('$RECEIVED_MESSAGE', function (event, data) {

  $scope.retrieveMessages();
  $scope.$apply();

 });
```

Service

```
angular
    .module('conversations')
    .factory('EventEmitter', ['$rootScope',
        function($rootScope) {

            var factory = {


                newMessage: function() {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('$RECEIVED_MESSAGE');
                }



            };

            return factory;

    }]);
```

Function in controller that watches firebase for changes

```
var notificationsRef = new Firebase(config.firebaseRef + 'notifications/' + $scope.authentication.uid);
notificationsRef.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {

    var snapshot = childSnapshot.val();

    if(snapshot.type === 'Conversation'){
      EventEmitter.newMessage();
    };

})
.catch(function(error) {
console.error("Error:", error);
});
```

Conversations Factory (omitted definition and other methods for brevity)

```
retrieveConversations: function(uid){

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var request = {
      uid: uid
    };

    $http.post(config.serverRef + '/conversations', request)
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available

        deferred.resolve(data);

      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        deferred.reject(status);
      });

    return deferred.promise;

},
```

Comment: From where is the event broadcasted?

Comment: It's broadcasted from a event handling / notification service that uses $rootScope.$broadcast('$RECEIVED_MESSAGE');

Comment: You need to show what triggers the `$rootScope.$broadcast`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not with the code but timing and execution. Calls were happening faster than the re-indexing of firebase data to elasticsearch. Solved with $timeout(function(){$scope.retrieveMessages()}, 1000).